# I cant setContentView() outside of Main Activity? Please read

Tags: java, android, xml

I can set the content view easily when within the main class whereas when I set it within a different class the app crashes.

Heres an example:

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //HERE <-----

            new SecondClass();
    }
}
```

SecondClass class:

```
public class SecondClass extends Activity
{
public SecondClass()
{
setContentView(R.layout.activity_info); //HERE <----
}
```

}

If you know why this problem occurs please say as it will many others as well as me.
Thanks,

Comment: Can you please show us the log of the error.  Also, why would you want to create an Activity within one, both having the same layout.  That seems to be a bigger problem.

Comment: My app is still crashing, heres the code : pastebin.com/d0PhLuf1  Thanks again @codeMagic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have a `constructor` in an `Activity`.

```
public SecondClass(){
setContentView(R.layout.activity_info); //HERE <----
 }
```

Remove that and put it inside `onCreate()` like you have in your first `Activity`.

And this isn't how you create a new instance of an `Activity`

```
 new SecondClass();
```

Create an instance of an `Activity` with an `Intent`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //HERE <-----

         Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondClass.class);
         startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what you are doing but you typically wouldn't do this because it would start the second `Activity` as soon as the first is created.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will implement this. If my code isnt following any logical practices its because everything Ive learnt with android java is self taught and not following tutorials. EDIT: I see what you meen, theres alot more code this is just the bare essentials of the problem.

Comment: You might want to consider Googling some tutorials and looking through [the docs here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html). [This guy normally has some good tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Im going to take an online free course on a site called coursera although it currently isnt setup yet. Btw thanks for the quick responce and help Id rep you if I could.

Comment: I think I've heard of some people using that for scala and other things so it may be decent. In the meantime, check out the links I gave you to get a headstart. SO is a great place to learn but learning some basics from simple tutorials would be a good start.

Comment: My app is still crashing, heres the code : http://pastebin.com/d0PhLuf1 Thanks again.

Comment: Hard to say without logcat output but probably didn't declare both of your `Activities` in your `manifest.xml`. All `Activities` need to be declared there. [manifest docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Comment: That sounds like the problem, I had no idea you had to declare activities. Ill read the link. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great answer! It worked after I declared the Activity within the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a new instance of an Activity that way, you must use the intent mechanism. See here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html. Then override the onCreate() method of the SecondActivity, call the super and setContentView().

Comment: Thanks for the links :D & quick response

Comment: I would upvote but unfortunately I have one off the required rep. Although I did accept thanks again! @svenoaks